# JavaScript: Object Property Value Shorthand for nested assignment

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an object

```
obj = {
    name: 'Karthi',
    age: 25,
    gender: 'Male'
}
```

and I want to assign some of the values to a key with the same name in another object.

```
objTar = {
    name: obj.name,
    age: obj.age
}
```

Is there a shorthand for the above "nested" assignment? I know there's a shorthand for flat assignments; eg., `objTar = { name, age }` given `name` and `age` are available in the lexical scope.

Don't suggest workarounds to achieve this please. Just let me know if this is "natively" supported.

Comment: Answering a question on JavaScript tag has become a competitive sport

Comment: [There is a proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements), but no there currently is no native support.

Answer (score -1):

**You can achieve this using below code.**

```
objTar = Object.assign({},{age:obj.age, gender:obj.gender})
```

Comment: That usage of `Object.assign` is totally pointless